# How to get different parameters to log in a .txt file with C#?

Tags: c#, logging

I am making an application for my game that stores all the user activity and other variables in a .txt file. I wrote the part to get the parameter and also the part to make a text file to write something down.
But I cant get to link these 2 parts.
I will post the code here, notice that I have int and string parameters who need to get written down.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;`



public class Levels_Menu : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GUISkin skin;

    void OnGUI()
    {

        GUI.skin = skin;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 750, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 300, 100), "EASY"))
        {
            //Application.LoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Easy");
            ApplicationLoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Easy");
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 450, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 300, 100), "NORMAL"))
        {
            //Application.LoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Normal");
            ApplicationLoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Normal");
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 150, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 300, 100), "HARD"))
        {
            //Application.LoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Hard");
            ApplicationLoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Hard");
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 + 150, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 300, 100), "SURVIVAL"))
        {
            //Application.LoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Survival");
            ApplicationLoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_Survival");
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 + 450, Screen.height / 2 - 100, 300, 100), "FIND THE COLOR"))
        {
            //Application.LoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_FindTheColor");
            ApplicationLoadLevel("Game_Difficulty_FindTheColor");
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 250, Screen.height / 2 - 300, 500, 100), "PLAY RANDOM LEVEL"))
        {
            //Application.LoadLevel(Random.Range(4, 8));
            ApplicationLoadLevel(Random.Range(4, 8));
        }

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 + 400, Screen.height / 2 - 300, 300, 100), "MAIN MENU"))
        {
            //Application.LoadLevel("Main_Menu");
            ApplicationLoadLevel("Main_Menu");
        }
    }

    private void ApplicationLoadLevel(string level)
    {
        Logger.LogThis(level);
        Application.LoadLevel(level);

    }

    private void ApplicationLoadLevel(int level)
    {
        Logger.LogThis(level);
        Application.LoadLevel(level);
    }

    public static class Logger
    {

         public static void LogThis()
    {
            string path = @"C:\temp\ExampleNew.txt";
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                File.Create(path);
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
                tw.WriteLine();
                tw.Close(); 
            }
            else if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
                tw.WriteLine();
                tw.Close(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears simply: rewrite `public static void LogThis()` as `public static void LogThis(string text)` and then, when you write to the text file, use `tw.WriteLine(text)`

Granted, this doesn't support directly writing the `int`, so you can either

1. use the `ToString()` method on the int when passing it as a parameter or
2. change the method signature to `public static void LogThis(object toWrite)`.

Finally, I would suggest refactoring your `LogThis` method to the following:

```
public static void LogThis(object toWrite)
{
    string path = @"C:\temp\ExampleNew.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path);
    }
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
    tw.WriteLine(toWrite);
    tw.WriteLine();
    tw.Close(); 
}
```

UPDATE: `TextWriter` implements `IDisposable`! Yahoo! Use a `using` statement to ensure the stream is closed and released:

```
public static void LogThis(object toWrite)
{
    string path = @"C:\temp\ExampleNew.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path);
    }
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        tw.WriteLine(toWrite);
        tw.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Close` internally closes `Dispose` and vice versa, but you're right, ideally wrapping it in a `using` statement should always be used with `IDisposable`s, because it guarantees the release of the resources even an exception is thrown. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02) for more.